# View's dataSource property set to nil after I set it

Tags: objective-c, ios5

New to iOS/Objective-C here. I've spent a lot of time trying to figure this out, but just can't manage it. Here's what's happening:

- Click a 'Graph' button on my RootViewController's view
- GraphViewController takes over, has a graphView property
- I set the graphView's dataSource property to self
- Checking self.graphView.dataSource with NSLog confirms that it does indeed point to self
- When GraphView's drawRect: is called, self.dataSource is set to (null), where I expected it to point to the GraphViewController object

To summarise: I'm instantiating the graphView property in the view controller, then setting its dataSource, but by the time the view's drawRect: is called the dataSource is no longer set.

GraphViewController.m:

```
#import "GraphViewController.h"
#import "GraphView.h"

@implementation GraphViewController

@synthesize graphView = _graphView;
@synthesize program = _program;

- (GraphView *)graphView {
    if(!_graphView) {
        _graphView = [[GraphView alloc] init];
        [_graphView setDataSource:(id)self];
    }
    return _graphView;
}

@end
```

GraphViewController.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "GraphView.h"

@interface GraphViewController : UIViewController
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet GraphView *graphView;
@end
```

GraphView.m:

```
#import "GraphView.h"

@implementation GraphView

@synthesize dataSource = _dataSource;

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
        NSLog(@"initWithFrame called, self.dataSource=%@", self.dataSource);
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    NSLog(@"drawRect:");
    NSLog(@"\tself=%@", self);
    NSLog(@"\tself.dataSource=%@", self.dataSource);  // is (null), shouldn't be
    [self.dataSource programToGraph];
}

@end
```

GraphView.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class GraphView;

@protocol GraphViewDataSource
- (id)programToGraph;
@end

@interface GraphView : UIView

@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet id <GraphViewDataSource> dataSource;

@end
```

Comment: To figure out where you made the mistake, people would need to see code where you instantiated the view, the declaration of the property, and probably the drawRect:, and where you confirmed the property was set correctly.

Comment: your datasource is getting released prematurely. You need to set its property to strong (instead of weak).

Comment: @Rog, making that strong would create a retain cycle in this case

Comment: @Rog, that's what I thought too, but the problem still occurs if the property is strong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it looks like the GraphViewController instance is being deallocated, which will nil out the dataSource property.

So you should go back and look at how you are creating and managing that GraphViewController. A common mistake is to create a view controller like that, then borrow its view and throw it into some other view controller's view hierarchy, and then let the original view controller just go away.

I would look at that, and if you don't see it there, post the code where you create and present the GraphViewController.

Oh, and where are you calling initWithFrame: from?? It almost looks like you could also have two different instances of GraphView floating around. Try logging 'self' along with self.datasource to check that also.

Comment: You're right Firoze, I checked the graphView property on the GraphViewController against the GraphView object, their addresses are different.

I'm not clear on how the GraphViewController is created to be honest. My root view controller has a 'Graph' button on it, which I ctrl+dragged across to the GraphViewController (which contains a GraphView), this created a segue for me.

I don't explicitly call initWithFrame, it must happen when the view is  created for display.

Comment: Ah, so it sounds like you have a graphview in your storyboard already. Then don't create (alloc/init) another one in code. Just set the datasource of the one in the storyboard.

Comment: Thank you, I'm much closer now. I wired the graphView property to the storyboard (I'd missed that), now the graphView's drawRect: is called twice, once with the dataSource set, the other without the dataSource. I can't figure out why it's being instantiated twice.

Comment: For anyone else who comes across this topic - `-drawRect:` was being called twice because I had accidentally dragged two views into the storyboard. I didn't realise until I looked in the scene editor.